# The best way to save the String Variable after being redirected Page in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, variables, redirect, static-variables

How can I save the form values as a string after the page is redirected?

I use a static variable, if the number of users on the site increases for example 20000, will the site have problems?

Which method is better?

1. Using a static variable?
2. session?
3. Cookies?
4. ViewBag?
5. View State?
6. sql server database?

Comment: the answer may depend on what you are saving and why you are saving it... you probably want to add more details here...

Comment: i need to save string. when the page being redirected or reloaded i need this string for select the record from database.

Comment: Still not much detail there...   Sounds like you'd just want to pass an id of a record.  So add that as a query parameter to the redirect (which is a GET).  Ex: redirect_url.com?id=the_record_id  To send something more complex, use an AJAX call and send JSON back to the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, There is no the best method, Only the most suitable method. The methods you list above all  have their own most suitable use cases.

From your comment, I think you may wanna redirect to another page with a string parameter, So you can try to use :

```
return RedirectToAction("actionName","controllerName",new { Name="xxx"});
```

It will send a get request: `acontrollerName/actionName?Name=xxx`.

Or, if you wanna save that string value for a long time, You can also try to use `Session` or `Database`. But one thing you need to consider is that you need to set the session time out according to the actual situation of your project.

==========================edited===========================

I think you can use Session to achieve it.

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSelectMenu(int selectedid)
        {
            TestModel selected = await _db.Table.FindAsync(selectedid);
             //set session
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Key", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selected));
            return RedirectToPage("MyPage");
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            //......

            //get session
            Input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestModel>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Key"));
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: i can do it with session but session can going to lower speed of server memory. it unusable for High number of users

Comment: If you have high number of users, I think you need to use db.